# About props in react native

Tags: react-native

[Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html)  says:

> props are set by the parent and they are **fixed** **throughout the lifetime** of a component.

This got me confused because that is NOT the case in React, in React, the **same instance** of component can receive different props throughout its lifetime (e.g. when parent just passes different value of props to same child, instance of child remains same, it just gets new props). Whereas above line claims same instance can't receive different props value in RN.

Is it any different in react native?

Also I can't open an issue if it is not a but on RN github, so in case doc is wrong, hopefully someone from RN community stumbles on this question.

Answer (score 1):

What the document should say is that the value of the props remains fixed for the lifetime of the component until it receives new props from it's parent or you specifically map different values using redux like third parties.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that the props **shouldn't be mutated** within the child component, they're not meant to be edited in the component that's receiving them.

You can learn more about props [here](https://kolosek.com/react-props-basic), although React is used for examples, everything applies to React Native as well, as React and React Native props function the same.